# Issue Using Git Source Control with Xcode in iOS 7

Tags: xcode

I have been having a problem with Xcode and git source control and I just reproduced it running through your tutorial while refreshing myself on merging. I basically end up with two working copies listed in the Source Control menu and then Xcode gets confused about the source control status of the project. I'm hoping you guys have some ideas.

Here is a [screenshot](https://docs.google.com/a/berkeley.edu/file/d/0B5hM-CTDF46gUWR0ZzR4OEs5Tk0/edit) of my source control menu to help understand the issue:
https://docs.google.com/a/berkeley.edu/file/d/0B5hM-CTDF46gUWR0ZzR4OEs5Tk0/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go to Xcode 5 Source Control Menu, choose Git, and Commit, and then check "Push To Remote" and select the different branch.

Answer (score 0):

I go to Source Control Menu, then Commit, and then check "Push To Remote" and select the different branch. (So I push my changes in one step.)

or

I switch to the other branch locally, pull the changes, then merge from my previous branch, then push this branch to the remote.